# cornerstonewadoimageloader.js not working, .dcm files not displayed

Tags: javascript, jquery, unpkg, dicomweb

We are using cornerstone wado image loader lib to load .dcm images. It was working well till few days, suddenly when we opened the viewer today, it is showing "Error: loadImageFromImageLoader: no image loader for imageId". after going through all checks, we found out that the file: https://unpkg.com/cornerstone-wado-image-loader that is embedded in the example page is not working and is showing a error called Rate exceeded. Even it seems the official lib example pages are not working. Here is for your information: https://rawgit.com/cornerstonejs/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader/master/examples/wadouri/index.html

any help from anyone, folks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing wrong with this website. It is a global outage for unpkg.com they seem to experience some issue and it is affecting hundreds (read tousends) of websites.
I changed my websites to use cdnjs.cloudflare.com instead and it's all good now.

(I now see cloudflare does not have your particular package. You can use jsdelivr.com instead: https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/cornerstone-wado-image-loader@3.0.6/dist/cornerstoneWADOImageLoader.min.js )

Answer (score 1):

unpkg.com is having "Rate exceeded" issue right now.

Your site is OK. Please switch to another cdn provider.